# Pc restart at every 10 sec

Tags: hard-drive, memory, motherboard, power-supply

I need some tips to troubleshoot my problem. Recently my pc restart by itself.

Things i did so far

- Swap motherboard (as initially i thought mobo failure)
- Disconnected the gpu ram hdd sdd from mobo and ran only the psu and mobo , problem still occur
- Jump start the mobo only with the psu connected , problem still occur  (assumed the power cables are faulty)
- Troubleshoot the psu using the thumbnail method and found out voltage are within acceptable range ( psu are able to run smoothly)

I have ran out of ideas to do the troubleshoot. Any more tips/ideas for my to fix the problem?

Thanks guys! Much appreciated!

Comment: So you have verified that the power supply and the motherboard are not the problem that sadly suggests the processor is to blame

Comment: This is going to sound crazy but are you sure you have the cooler mounted to the CPU? A friend of mine years ago had a similar problem because he forgot that step.

Comment: Yeah i did ! Even applied a new thermal paste..